# Agrupar y Ordenar en Sql

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql, estructuras-de-datos, ordenamiento

Hola buenos dias solicito una ayuda o guia para tratar de resolver una consulta en sql, cabe notar que soy nuevo en este mundo; estoy tratando realizar una consulta que muestre el ultimo registro por codigo de item es decir tengo unos valores como codigo de item, fecha y costo, necesito estructurar una consulta que me de el ultimo registro de ese item en base al costo maximo y la fecha.

Este es el ejemplo de mi codigo.

```
select CodItem, Descrip1, Costo, convert(varchar(10),FechaE,105)   as [Fecha de Compra], NumeroD, TipoCom, CodProv, Cantidad

from saitemcom

group by CodItem, Descrip1, Costo, FechaE, NumeroD, TipoCom, CodProv, Cantidad

having TipoCom = 'H'

order by CodItem,FechaE Desc
```

Y mi resultado arrojado es este:

```
CodItem Descrip1    Costo   Fecha de Compra NumeroD TipoCom CodProv Cantidad
00001   Porta Vaso Ram  159.51000   09-06-2011  00000051    H   313816680   2.00000
00001   Porta Vaso Ram  333.34000   11-03-2011  00001388    H   29849302-0  6.00000
00001   Porta Vaso Ram  210.88000   17-07-2009  00000980    H   314418777   2.00000
00004   Porta Ipod Ram  276.48000   17-07-2009  00000980    H   314418777   1.00000
00005   Porta Iphone Ram    100000.00000    22-04-2017  000053  H   404366709   2.00000
00005   Porta Iphone Ram    276.48000   17-07-2009  00000980    H   314418777   1.00000
000164  Manilla Compuerta Chevrolet Silverado ce    166.50000   26-05-2010  00000201    H   29849302-0  1.00000
00031   Rejilla Stop Toyota Corolla 09  266.07000   26-05-2010  00000201    H   29849302-0  1.00000
001-031 Alarma Up-Grade Alsama  38094.86000 23-11-2016  0000024 H   407318675   5.00000
001-031 Alarma Up-Grade Alsama  31745.72000 22-11-2016  002 H   407318675   1.00000
```

Ahora si pueden ver el código 00001 se repite varias veces yo necesito de ese código el ultimo registro con el valor mas alto y obviamente la fecha y asi sucesivamente con los demas codigos como por ejemplo el 001-0031 o el 000005 que también presenta el mismo caso.

Pero no se que buscar para poder hacer esta consulta no consigo lograrlo ni con group by, ni con max porque entonces este me muestra un solo registro de toda la tabla y no uno de cada uno ni con last_value; no se si es que no estoy agrupando de la forma correcta.

Me podrian por favor chicos y chicas del foro!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba cualquiera de estas sentencias, adaptándolas a tu tabla, a ver si te resulta.

En la primera estas seleccionando el registro con max de Costo sobre una agrupación por coditem ([AQUÍ](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/sql/sql_first_record_per_group.htm) tienes mas información)

En la segunda sentencia, mediante el uso de common table expression (CTE).

*Realiza pruebas sobre estas sentencias para aprender como funcionan.*

**1º OPCIÓN:** SELECT CODITEM,MAX(COSTO) AS PRECIO FROM saitemcom GROUP BY CODITEM

**2º OPCIÓN:** WITH CTE AS 
(
select ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY CodItem ORDER BY CodItem,Costo DESC) AS TOTAL,Descrip1,Costo from saitemcom
)
select Descrip1,Costo from cte where total=1

Comment: Gua Guau muchas gracias de verdad muchisimas gracias raul, el articulo que me recomendastes de:

"En la primera estas seleccionando el registro con max de Costo sobre una agrupación por coditem (AQUÍ tienes mas información)"

Fue con el que me guie excelente material ese que me compartistes con ese me guie y con ese lo logre mi codigo quedo asi y funciono de maravilla!.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

A la final gracias a la ayuda del amigo raul pude reslver con su explicacion quedando el codigo de este modo.

```
select it.coditem, it.descrip1, it.costo, it.cantidad, CONVERT(DATE,it.fechae,105) as FechaUC

from saitemcom it

inner join ( select coditem, max(FechaE) as UltimaFC from saitemcom group by coditem) inside on inside.coditem = it.coditem
and inside.UltimaFC = it.fechae 

order by CodItem
```

De verdad el enlace que el me compartió arriba a pesar de estar en ingles fue de mucha pero muchisima ayuda para poder completar este proceso.

Sin el y el creador del articulo me ubiese sido muy dificil lograrlo muchas gracias.

Comment: Genial Ivan me alegro te haya funcionado, pero veo que estas haciendo un join  sobre la misma tabla que no se si realmente se puede evitar...¿podrias por favor probar esta sql a ver si te da el mismo resultado? 
select coditem, max(FechaE) as UltimaFC,descrip1, costo, cantidad, CONVERT(DATE,fechae,105) as FechaUC from saitemcom 
group by coditem order by CodItem